# Local DNS not updating

Tags: windows-server-2008

We added a second Web server to our network.  I moved one of our Web sites to the new Web server.  The old Web server has an external IP and has not changed.  I went to our domain registrar and changed the external IP number of the Web site that was moved.  Outside of our network the moved Web site displays correctly, but inside the network the DNS server does not resolve the web address.  Our local domain controller is Windows Server 2008 Core.  What do I have to do to get the domain controller to pick up on the change?  I have tried rebooted and ipconfig /flushdns.

I should also mention that the www.movedsite.com resolves to the old internal IP address but movedsite.com returns 'could not find host movedsite.com'.

Comment: What's up with the -1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is the internal and external domain name the same?  Meaning is your AD domain the same movedsite.com as your external?  If so, you'll need to manually update the www record in DNS internally to the new IP.

If they are separate, you can flush the DNS cache on the server, and then do an nslookup on the server to verify it is getting the right IP from the correct DNS server that you are forwarding external lookups to.

Comment: No, they are different.  The web site is movedsite.com and our domain is companyname.com.  How do I flush the DNS cache on server?  I did a ipconfig /flushdns.  Needless to say, I am new at this.

Comment: ON the DC, inside DNS admin, right click server, clear cache.  Also post an NSLOOKUP output from the server itself here (masking the IPs and names), do an "nslookup www.movedsite.com" and post the masked results.

Comment: This is a server core installation.  Not sure what to do with it.

Comment: >nslookup movedsite.com
Server:  domaincontroller.mycompany.com
Address:  172.20.0.11

Name:    movedsite.com


>nslookup www.movedsite.com
Server:  domaincontroller.mycompany.com
Address:  172.20.0.11

Name:    oldwebserver.mycompany.com
Addresses:  172.20.0.21
          172.20.0.20
Aliases:  www.movedsite.com

Comment: Sounds like you might be using your internal DNS server as authoritative for the external domain as well.  You'll need to load up DNS admin tools and connect to the w2k8 dns server.  Then change the entries in DNS to the new IP (whether resolving to the new external or new internal is based on how it is currently setup).

Comment: 172.20.0.11 is the address of the domain controller.  172.20.0.21 172.20.0.20 are the nics in the old Web server.  You see that the lookup without the www in front returned the domain controller and nothing else

Comment: Ok, let me get those tools installed.  I didn't set this up and the person who did is not available.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I cant seem to find DNS tools to download.  I have AD Tools installed, but I don't think this is what you are referring too?

Comment: See here: http://www.petri.co.il/remotely-manage-windows-server-2008-mmc.htm

Comment: I went to a full install of Windows 2008 Server and opened Admin Tools > DNS Server.  Then I pointed to the core server and I could see that there was an A record pointed to the old Web server.  I updated this and all is good.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Check your hosts file - the site/IP may be hard-coded.

`c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Open the file in notepad.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the DNS record set up with the registrar for external name resolution you need to provide an internal record delegation pointing to the registrar's servers.

This is done by opening the Windows DNS Server. Right click on the domain -> New Delegation record. Add the domain and then the registrar's name servers like

```
ns10.dnsmadeeasy.com
ns10.dnsmadeeasy.com
ns10.dnsmadeeasy.com
```